# Copying arrays into arrays with different data types

Tags: vb.net

So I've got a character array, but I need to copy it into an integer array. But because they are different data types i can't do that easily. Any ideas how to do this? 
(I can't just start off with an integer array, it has to be copied from a character array)
Thanks in advance

Comment: An array element is pretty much exactly like a variable.  Could you assign a `Char` value to an `Integer` variable?  Of course not.  You would have to convert the `Char` to an `Integer` in the appropriate way and then assign the result to the variable.  That's what you need to do here too, but multiple times.

Comment: Please don't specify language, technology, etc, in your title.  That's what tags are for.

Comment: What is the content of the char array? Unicode chars? What's the use of the Integer conversion? Are you trying to send this array over a communication link of sort? Something else? You should describe the problem you're trying to solve, maybe the actual solution is not converting chars to Integers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if thats the case but, chars are numerical ASCII codes for machine that are converted to "visible" chars on screen.
If you make

```
Dim charTable As Char() = {"a", "b", "c"}

    For Each letter In charTable
        MsgBox(letter)
        MsgBox(Convert.ToByte(letter))

    Next
```

you will get numerical respresentation of those letters.

Things will complicte if you have string such as "abc"
then you need to break this string to single chars and then convert it to ints like above.

```
  Dim charTable As String() = {"ab", "abc", "c"}
        Dim singlechar As Char
        For Each letter In charTable
            For Each singlechar In letter
                MsgBox(letter)
                MsgBox(singlechar)
                MsgBox(Convert.ToByte(singlechar))
            Next
        Next
```